# Making image gallery in table but responsive

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, gallery, tabular

I am making a photography gallery and I have problems with keeping everything aligned.

I should point out right away that this gallery would be used by other people and I can't control what images they upload when it comes to aspect ratio.

I created a gallery using 3x col-md-4 and each column holds one photograph.
The problem is occurring when I have one vertical, one horizontal and one panoramic image in the same row.

Considering different aspect ratio they don't get aligned vertically. 
I fixed this by creating class for each and including padding top specifically for that aspect ratio but there are way too many variables when it comes to image size and I would need 100 rows of css to get them all covered.

I would really like to make this gallery with tables because it would have vertical alignment no matter the image size but then I would lose responsiveness.

Is there a way to make this happen? Some trick on how to include table and make td responsive.

Keep in mind I am very new at this and would appreciate "spoon feeding".

For reference ,here is my first website I made when I had no idea about bootstrap and that has the gallery style I want to achieve - http://www.robertmaric.net/gallery/landscape
you can notice that every photograph is perfectly aligned no matter the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

In your css some issue. 
You change css code:

In **Layout.css line 112.**
change

```
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
color: #999;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
padding: 10px 30px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100%;
```

and 
your table css give:

```
 margin-left:160px;
```